DateRangePicker from Material UI not displaying
Well, I am using DateRangePicker from this module, but it doesn't appear on the UI.
import DateRangePicker, { DateRange } from '@mui/lab/DateRangePicker';
...
<DateRangePicker
  startText="Start Date"
  endText="End Date"
  value={dateRangeValue}
  onChange={(newValue) => {
    setDateRangeValue(newValue);
  }}
  renderInput={(startProps, endProps) => (
    <Fragment>
      <TextField {...startProps} />
      <Box sx={{ mx: 2 }}> to </Box>
      <TextField {...endProps} />
    </Fragment>
  )}
/>
...

Some answers show that I have to use '@mui/x-date-pickers-pro/DateRangePicker' module, but it seems crashes with @mui/labs, so no idea about that.
Could you help with this to display DateRangePicker on my UI working correctly?
Thanks for your help, community..
